# get request download link not downloaded inside of web view in android when without internet

Tags: android, csv, webview, download, android-download-manager

I am trying to get a link to download CSV file from an android web view. I have a web view in my Android Application. When a user goes to the web view and clicks a link to download a file using get request, it is downloaded with a new browser page. My requirement is to download the file inside a web view, use won't see the download link.

Assume that you have an IoT device that only has WLAN connectivity. Now this device should operate using a given WLAN connection, and configured with the SSID and password. Also, the device acts as access point mode and gets a user interface and gets a download link.

Now, the device is connected with a mobile app for web viewing. If you click a link to download a csv file, downloaded with new browser page, My requirement is the file download inside of web view .
I also tried using the download manager, but not downloading the inside of web view.
I would appreciate any help. Thank you

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimetype);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

});

Comment: Links will open in default browser of your device. Unless you overwrite onNewUrl() method. (Or however it is called, i forgot). In that method you just use loadUrl().